# how to install mongodb-c driver in ubuntu and use in coturn server

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, turn, coturn

i am using coturn and i want to use mongodb as a database
when i run the turnserver it shows

```
SQLite supported, default database location is /var/lib/turn/turndb
0: Redis supported
0: PostgreSQL supported
0: MySQL supported
0: MongoDB is not supported
0: 
0: Default Net Engine version: 3 (UDP thread per CPU core)
```

i have installed coturn
using this command

```
sudo apt-get install coturn
```

and the coturn [docs](https://github.com/leecade/coturn/blob/32d52f5006e1d9cdce4060464cabe7e261502177/INSTALL#L377) says

> mongo-c-driver packages are not available "automatically".    MongoDB
> support will not be compiled, unless you install it "manually"    before
> the TURN server compilation. Refer to
> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver for installation
> instructions  of the driver.

and tried to install mongo c driver by following this [guide](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html)

**Install libmongoc with a Package Manager**

```
apt-get install libmongoc-1.0-0
```

**Build environment on Unix**

On Debian / Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake libssl-dev libsasl2-dev
```

**Configuring the build**
Preparing a build from a git repository clone

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver.git
$ cd mongo-c-driver
$ git checkout 1.17.0  # To build a particular release
$ python build/calc_release_version.py > VERSION_CURRENT
$ mkdir cmake-build
$ cd cmake-build
$ cmake -DENABLE_AUTOMATIC_INIT_AND_CLEANUP=OFF ..
```

**Executing a build**

Building on Unix, macOS, and Windows (MinGW-W64 and MSYS2)¶

```
$ cmake --build .
$ sudo cmake --build . --target install
```

and

`~/mongo-c-driver/cmake-build$`cmake --build . help

returned

```
Unknown argument help
Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
Options:
  <dir>          = Project binary directory to be built.
  --target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
                   May only be specified once.
  --config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
  --clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                   (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
  --use-stderr   = Ignored.  Behavior is default in CMake >= 3.0.
  --             = Pass remaining options to the native tool.
```

and

**Generating the documentation**

```
cmake -DENABLE_MAN_PAGES=ON -DENABLE_HTML_DOCS=ON ..
```

returned

```
-- No CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE selected, defaulting to RelWithDebInfo
file VERSION_CURRENT contained BUILD_VERSION 1.17.0
-- Build and install static libraries
  -- Using bundled libbson
libbson version (from VERSION_CURRENT file): 1.17.0
--     struct timespec found
Adding -fPIC to compilation of bson_static components
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (_message):
  Could NOT find Sphinx (missing: SPHINX_EXECUTABLE)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  build/cmake/FindSphinx.cmake:10 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  src/libbson/CMakeLists.txt:444 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/user/mongo-c-driver/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/user/mongo-c-driver/cmake-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

cmake --build . --target mongoc-doc

make: *** No rule to make target 'mongoc-doc'.  Stop.
```

and when i restart the coturn server it still shows that mongodb is not supported

how can i resolve this issue

Comment: I have the same problem, can you give me the solution

Answer (score -1):

sudo apt-get install python3-sphinx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some details, code-only answers, it's not self-explanatory

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.